# How to change tomtom map's marker in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

Trying to add a custom icon marker to tomtom maps on android project

here the function am using for this :

```
    private fun addingStation() {
        val i = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert, null)
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference("station")
// Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (ds in dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    val name = ds.child("station_name").getValue(String::class.java)
                    val stationLongitude = ds.child("station_longitude").getValue(String::class.java)
                    val stationLatitude = ds.child("station_latitude").getValue(String::class.java)
                    val longitude = stationLongitude.let { java.lang.Double.parseDouble(it!!) }
                    val latitude = stationLatitude.let { java.lang.Double.parseDouble(it!!) }
                    val currentLatLng = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
                    val balloon = SimpleMarkerBalloon(name)
                    map.addMarker(MarkerBuilder(currentLatLng).
                        markerBalloon(balloon)
                        .icon(i))
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                println("failed")
            }
        })
        val currentLatLng = LatLng(31.233334, 30.033333)
        val balloon = SimpleMarkerBalloon("cairo are Here")
        map.addMarker(MarkerBuilder(currentLatLng).markerBalloon(balloon))

    }
```

The code gives me this error :

Required:Icon! , Found: Drawable?

after debugging the line that causes the error is

```
                    map.addMarker(MarkerBuilder(currentLatLng).
                        markerBalloon(balloon)
                        .icon(i))
```

Comment: I think in kotlin it is being processed using another function or external way, but even `Icon.Factory.fromResources(context, R.drawable.ic_favourites)` is not working in kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a typical image file (png for example) in your drawable folder, you can use `Icon.Factory.fromResources` function:

```
tomtomMap.addMarker(MarkerBuilder(latLng)
    .icon(Icon.Factory.fromResources(this, R.drawable.pin)))
```

If your image is defined as an android vector drawable, you can create a `BitmapDrawable` from it and use it inside `Icon.Factory.fromDrawable` function:

```
val drawable = this.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.marker, theme)

val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    drawable.intrinsicWidth,
    drawable.intrinsicHeight,
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
)

val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
drawable.draw(canvas)

val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(this.resources, bitmap)

tomtomMap.addMarker(MarkerBuilder(latLng)
    .icon(Icon.Factory.fromDrawable("name", bitmapDrawable)))
```